# Integration of Zabbix Graph Data into Itop Server Info

Tags: linux, monitoring, zabbix, zabbix-api

I am Trying To Get Graph Data From Zabbix Thorough graph.get method via Zabbix API to integrate it into Itop but don't know exactly how to approach this. any guide or resource regarding this would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Zabbix but there are several ways to do this depending on what Zabbix offers.

**1 - Embed the graph in an iframe**
If Zabbix allows to display the graph through an dedicated URL, then you can use the [iFrame dashlet extension](https://store.itophub.io/en_US/products/itop-iframe-dashlet) to display it in a dashboard within iTop.

This requires no development skills.

**2 - Create your own extension**
You can also develop your own iTop extension and query the Zabbix webservices yourself, then display the data as you wish (either a dashlet or directly in the page).

Check [this page](https://www.itophub.io/wiki/page?id=2_7_0%3Acustomization%3Astart#by_writing_your_own_extension) for how to make your own extension.
Check [this repo](https://github.com/Combodo/itop-iframe-dashlet) for an example on how to make a dashlet (the iFrame one for example)